# Login and password in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a par of code c# to login but doesn't work it gives me the message in Else :

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Connection = @"data source=LOCALHOST;initial catalog=CVtech;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=123";
        string Requete = "select * from Agent where Login ='" + UserLogin.Text + " and PPR = " + UserPass.Text+"'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Requete, Connection);
        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(Ds);

        if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow[] dr = Ds.Tables[0].Select();

            Session["Code"] = dr[0]["PPR"].ToString();

            Response.Redirect("cv.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(" message d'erreur login et mot de passe erroné");
        }
    }
```

i have a login : "Ach" and PPR = 1

Thank you

Comment: Try debugging the code, obviously the row count is `0`. Also, **please** fix this: `string Requete = "select * from Agent where Login ='" + UserLogin.Text + " and PPR = " + UserPass.Text+"'";` you are begging for SQL injection.

Comment: You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: inspect the sql string you create - you'll see that you are missing some quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the string value in the sql request.

```
string Requete = "select * from Agent where Login ='" + UserLogin.Text + " and PPR = " + UserPass.Text + "'";
```

should be

```
string Requete = "select * from Agent where Login ='" + UserLogin.Text + "' and PPR = '" + UserPass.Text + "'";
```

Also, you should look into sql injection and parametrizing your queries. I don't use DataAdapters much but I believe it will look something like.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=LOCALHOST;initial catalog=CVtech;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=123");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(); 

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Agent where Login = @login and PPR = @ppr", connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
command.Parameters["@login"].Value = UserLogin.Text;

command.Parameters.Add("@ppr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
command.Parameters["@ppr"].Value = UserPass.Text;

da.SelectCommand = command;

DataSet Ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(Ds);
```

For more details see

How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Heed the advice above and use SQLParameters!

Comment: `+1` that's right. Also consider to suggest him parameterized queries **with an example**.

Comment: no , i have this error  in da.Fill(Ds);:
La requête paramétrée '(@login varchar(50),@ppr int)select * from Agent where Login = @' attend le paramètre @login, qui n'a pas été fourni.

Comment: Double check against the code above, I don't think you are using the latest version.